Magento API Date filter
Is it possible to create a Date filter to fetch orders created only  in last two days using API , without hard-coded values ?
Something like this:
http://<magento_host>/rest/V1/orders?
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=from&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=(current date - 2 days)
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=created_at&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=to&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=(current date)

Example in PHP to Fetch Orders
<?php

$endDate = new DateTime();
$startDate = new DateTime();
$startDate->modify('-2 days');

$endDateStr = $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$startDateStr = $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$apiUrl = 'https://your-magento-store.com/rest/V1/orders';
$query = http_build_query([
    'searchCriteria' => [
        'filterGroups' => [
            [
                'filters' => [
                    [
                        'field' => 'created_at',
                        'value' => $startDateStr,
                        'condition_type' => 'from'
                    ],
                    [
                        'field' => 'created_at',
                        'value' => $endDateStr,
                        'condition_type' => 'to'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);

$fullUrl = $apiUrl . '?' . $query;

// Initialize cURL session
$ch = curl_init($fullUrl);

// Set cURL options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
]);

// Execute the cURL session
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Close the cURL session
curl_close($ch);

// Handle the response
$responseData = json_decode($response, true);
print_r($responseData);

THANKS.
